# How to add multiple image upload metabox for a particular post type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a theme in which I have created some custom post type `products` and some custom meta boxes to submit their respective custom information like its cost and expiry date.

By doing some search `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`, I was able to add a featured image column to upload featured image related to a particular post. But it only allows me to add single image and I want to upload multiple images related to one particular custom post .For example different images of single product.

For this I found different solutions on internet and one of them which I found the most suitable to my problem is [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/), but again it only allows me to upload only one image but different than featured image.

Does WordPress has any functionality to upload multiple images like featured image upload particularly for single post or is there any plugin for this task?

Comment: Thanks Pratyusha for correction and I got the answer I can uploag multiple images through the media upload button bellow the title of the post and can display those images in a gallery on front end by using gallery shortcode for-eg:-'<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery size="thumbnail"]'); ?>'

Comment: Please, add your solution as an Answer, so it doesn't remain in the "Unanswered" list.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_post_gallery_so_14445904' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'print_scripts_so_14445904' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'print_scripts_so_14445904' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_gallery_so_14445904', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add custom Meta Box to Posts post type
 */
function add_post_gallery_so_14445904() 
{
    add_meta_box(
        'post_gallery',
        'Studio Image Uploader',
        'post_gallery_options_so_14445904',
        'post',// here you can set post type name
        'normal',
        'core'
    );
}

/**
 * Print the Meta Box content
 */
function post_gallery_options_so_14445904() 
{
    global $post;
    $gallery_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'gallery_data', true );

    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'noncename_so_14445904' );
?>

<div id="dynamic_form">

    <div id="field_wrap">
    <?php 
    if ( isset( $gallery_data['image_url'] ) ) 
    {
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $gallery_data['image_url'] ); $i++ ) 
        {
        ?>

        <div class="field_row">

          <div class="field_left">
            <div class="form_field">
              <label>Image URL</label>
              <input type="text"
                     class="meta_image_url"
                     name="gallery[image_url][]"
                     value="<?php esc_html_e( $gallery_data['image_url'][$i] ); ?>"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field_right image_wrap">
            <img src="<?php esc_html_e( $gallery_data['image_url'][$i] ); ?>" height="48" width="48" />
          </div>

          <div class="field_right">
            <input class="button" type="button" value="Choose File" onclick="add_image(this)" /><br />
            <input class="button" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="remove_field(this)" />
          </div>

          <div class="clear" /></div> 
        </div>
        <?php
        } // endif
    } // endforeach
    ?>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none" id="master-row">
    <div class="field_row">
        <div class="field_left">
            <div class="form_field">
                <label>Image URL</label>
                <input class="meta_image_url" value="" type="text" name="gallery[image_url][]" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field_right image_wrap">
        </div> 
        <div class="field_right"> 
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Choose File" onclick="add_image(this)" />
            <br />
            <input class="button" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="remove_field(this)" /> 
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="add_field_row">
      <input class="button" type="button" value="Add Field" onclick="add_field_row();" />
    </div>

</div>

  <?php
}

/**
 * Print styles and scripts
 */
function print_scripts_so_14445904()
{
    // Check for correct post_type
    global $post;
    if( 'post' != $post->post_type )// here you can set post type name
        return;
    ?>  
    <style type="text/css">
      .field_left {
        float:left;
      }

      .field_right {
        float:left;
        margin-left:10px;
      }

      .clear {
        clear:both;
      }

      #dynamic_form {
        width:580px;
      }

      #dynamic_form input[type=text] {
        width:300px;
      }

      #dynamic_form .field_row {
        border:1px solid #999;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding:10px;
      }

      #dynamic_form label {
        padding:0 6px;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add_image(obj) {
            var parent=jQuery(obj).parent().parent('div.field_row');
            var inputField = jQuery(parent).find("input.meta_image_url");

            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?TB_iframe=true');

            window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
                var url = jQuery(html).find('img').attr('src');
                inputField.val(url);
                jQuery(parent)
                .find("div.image_wrap")
                .html('<img src="'+url+'" height="48" width="48" />');

                // inputField.closest('p').prev('.awdMetaImage').html('<img height=120 width=120 src="'+url+'"/><p>URL: '+ url + '</p>'); 

                tb_remove();
            };

            return false;  
        }

        function remove_field(obj) {
            var parent=jQuery(obj).parent().parent();
            //console.log(parent)
            parent.remove();
        }

        function add_field_row() {
            var row = jQuery('#master-row').html();
            jQuery(row).appendTo('#field_wrap');
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Save post action, process fields
 */
function update_post_gallery_so_14445904( $post_id, $post_object ) 
{
    // Doing revision, exit earlier **can be removed**
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )  
        return;

    // Doing revision, exit earlier
    if ( 'revision' == $post_object->post_type )
        return;

    // Verify authenticity
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['noncename_so_14445904'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    // Correct post type
    if ( 'post' != $_POST['post_type'] ) // here you can set post type name
        return;

    if ( $_POST['gallery'] ) 
    {
        // Build array for saving post meta
        $gallery_data = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['gallery']['image_url'] ); $i++ ) 
        {
            if ( '' != $_POST['gallery']['image_url'][ $i ] ) 
            {
                $gallery_data['image_url'][]  = $_POST['gallery']['image_url'][ $i ];
            }
        }

        if ( $gallery_data ) 
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_data', $gallery_data );
        else 
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_data' );
    } 
    // Nothing received, all fields are empty, delete option
    else 
    {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_data' );
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ooh thanks for telling me that Brasofilo. 
And the right answer is one can upload multiple images through the media upload button bellow the title of the post and can display those images in a gallery on front end by using gallery shortcode for-eg:-

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery size="thumbnail"]'); ?>
```